# Django 1.6 name select is not defined

Tags: python, django, forms, choicefield

I'm trying to show a dropdown menu in my template, but I get the following error

```
File "forms.py" in DropdownSelectionForm
  101.     selection = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MY_CHOICES, widget = Select)

Exception Type: NameError at /
Exception Value: name 'Select' is not defined
```

here is the template where I'm trying to show the form

```
 <form action="/doclistings/" method="post" >{% csrf_token %}
            <select class="form-control" id="s1" NAME="selection">
              <option><b>Find a Doctor...</b></option>
              {% for value, text in form.selection.field.choices %}
                <option value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
```

Here is forms.py

```
MY_CHOICES = (
    ('Dermatologist', 'Dermatologist'),
    ('Dentist', 'Dentist'),
    ('Opthalmologist', 'Opthalmologist'),
)

class DropdownSelectionForm(forms.Form):
    selection = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MY_CHOICES, widget = Select)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like anything else in Python, you need to reference the object properly. In this case Select is made available via the forms module, exactly like ChoiceField.

```
selection = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MY_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python can't find `Select`, I see you have imported `django.forms`, so try `widget=forms.Select`